# events across two directories in python

Tags: python, events, mininet

I have this directory structure:

```
/home/anusha/mininet/custom/myfile1.py

/home/anusha/pox/ext/myfile2.py
```

Is it possible to raise an event in `myfile1` (with 2 arguments) and listen for that event in `myfile2` and write a handler in `myfile2`?

I am using Python 2.

Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve and why the directory structure is relevant. What do you mean event? Assume you are talking about some kind of IPC (InterProcess Communication) vs. just plain importing and calling a function in `myfile2.py`

Comment: @AChampion In `myfile1.py`, I want to do something like event.raise() for which the handler should be in `myfile2.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you open a shell, navigate to /home/anusha, and enter

```
python minuet/custom/myfile1.py
```

Then suppose you open a second shell, again navigate to home/anusha, and enter

```
python pox/ext/myfile2.py
```

Now you have two instances of python running in two separate processes. The second instance cannot handle an event raised in the first instance, or vice versa.

Or as AChampion said, you could include this line in myfile1.py:

```
import myfile2
```

In that case, you run a single instance of *python myfile1.py*, and the handler could be in myfile2.py.

(todo: explain how to append to library search path)

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. So is there anyway wherein I can communicate between these two processes?

Comment: AChampion mentioned InterProcess Communication. Traditional sockets are probably the most widely used and portable approach. Pipes might be a distant second.

Comment: If you can launch one process from another (e.g. [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html) module) then there are some higher level means of passing information between the processes (e.g. `multiprocessing.Queue`)